# how to add user information to a powershell table

Tags: powershell

Im attempting to learn powerscript and was wondering what i'm doing wrong here >

```
Foreach($result in $results){
$userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()

$row = $table.NewRow()
 $row.Name = $userEntry.displayName
 $row.UserID = $userEntry.sAMAccountName
 $row.Department = $userEntry.department

 $table.Rows.Add($row)
}
```

What i want is for the userdata to output into the proper cells of my table, but what i'm getting is 'System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection" repeated in each cell.

when i use the same format but output with

```
Foreach($result in $results){
$userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
Write-Output('' + "Name: " + $userEntry.displayName + "`r`n" + " " +"AccountInfo:"   +$userEntry.sAMAccountName + "`r`n" + " " + "Dept: " + $userEntry.department)

}
```

It's correct

what's the difference with table information?

Thanks everyone, i'm now looking to add this information to a worksheet, have it currently as:

```
#Excel worksheet
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$objExcel.Visible = $True 
$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
```

but now how would I get my foreach statement values to print onto the excel worksheet, or onto the workbook that is created with the statement??

Comment: Nvm got it, ended up having to swap my format to something more iterative >                                                         foreach ($result in $results)

{

    $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    
    $item.Cells.Item($i,1) = $userEntry.displayName.value

    $item.Cells.Item($i,2) = $userEntry.sAMAccountName.value
    
    $item.Cells.Item($i,3) = $userEntry.department.value
   

    $i++

}                                                                    Thanks guys! FNG formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the value property

$user.propertyName.value

Answer (score 2):

I would say the answer is in your $user.Foo type, and the way PowerShell handles collections. Compare:

```
$user.Foo | Get-Member
```

and

```
, $user.Foo | Get-Member
```

Because $user.Foo *looks* like a scalar, but is in fact collection, $row.Foo = $user.Foo  will show type rather than value.

How would you solve it? Two options:

```
$row.Foo = -join $user.Foo
```

or

```
$row.Foo = $user.Foo[0]
```

HTH
Bartek